# How can I determine if a connection to a webserver is using Perfect Forward Secrecy?

Tags: c#, ssl, https

I have a C# program that connects to a webserver and displays the expiration date of the SSL certificate.

What I would like to know is how to determine if the connection is using Perfect Forward Secrecy [PFS]?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ServerCertificateValidationCallback;
            ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;

            var request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.microsoft.com/");

            var response = request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static bool ServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Certificate expires on " + certificate.GetExpirationDateString());

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Preface: I'm not a cryptographer.

Per [this Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/47923) answer, you want to look at the agreed upon cipher suite, namely the key exchange piece of the suite. According to that, anything based on Diffie-Hellman provides perfect forward secrecy. As erickson points out in the comments, this could be untrue and you'll want to understand the security complications of assuming Perfect Forward Secrecy is present when it really is not.

With that, you're looking for [`SslStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That will allow you to gain access to the key exchange properties that you need.

It is not as easy as using a `WebRequest` or even a `HttpRequest`. You're going to have to write out the connection yourself. An example looks like:

```
string host = "www.microsoft.com";

using (var client = new TcpClient(host, 443))
using (var stream = client.GetStream())
using (var sslStream = new SslStream(stream))
{
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

    // figure out if sslStream.KeyExchangeAlgorithm support PFS here
}
```

In theory, KeyExchangeAlgorithm is a enumeration. And you could do `if(sslStream.KeyExchangeAlgorithm == ExchangeAlgorithmType.DiffieHellman)` and you'll know the answer<sup>[1]</sup>. But according to [this Microsoft Forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d0298622-a7cc-40e8-a4bf-8b74696ff548/sslstreamkeyexchangealgorithm-44550?forum=netfxbcl), `ExchangeAlgorithmType` may be 44550 which is equivalent to Elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman. Elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman does support Perfect Forward Secrecy.

If you want to modify your current code to make all of this happen in one connection, the remote certificate is available at `sslStream.RemoteCertificate` so you can get the certificate expiration date.

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> It is possible that not all Diffie-Hellman exchanges support Perfect Forward Secrecy. Again, consider the security complications of this.</sup>

Comment: I would have to read up, but I believe there are DH modes that *don't* provide PFS. I think you need to look more specifically for *ephemeral* DH key agreement (EDH_XXX cipher suites).

Comment: Look for DHE (EDH; Diffie-Hellman ephemeral) and ECDHE (EECDH; Elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman ephemeral). Only these key agreement algorithms provide PFS. DH, ECDH and RSA don't.

Comment: Steven, am I correct in my understanding that you are saying if one creates a connection using WebRequest.Create then there is no way to determine what sort of encryption is being used?

Comment: @zakjan MSDN says "DiffieHellman - The Diffie Hellman ephemeral key exchange algorithm". Since, it specifically says ephemeral, I guess it's safe to assume that it is ephemeral. Also, according to the microsoft forum post, 44550 = ECDH Ephemeral.